# Display Problem Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: display, themes

I am all new in this Ubuntu Universe and I have a problem. I tried to install Gnome Shell 3.6, so that I can use a theme downloaded from http://ubuntuthemes.org. I did not manage to do so, but I have this problem instead:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas how to solve this and install the theme?